# Item Not Found-error in QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()-call when space in path on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pyside6, qfiledialog

I'm experiencing strange behaviour in a `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName()`-call. When the dialog has to deal with a path with a space in it, either when I try to create a new folder to save the file in or when trying to save a file (i.e. complete the call regularly), the dialog results in an Item or a File Not Found error message dialog.

System details:

- PySide 6.5.2
- Python 3.11
- Windows 10 Pro

MRE:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import QStandardPaths
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMainWindow, QApplication

default_path = QStandardPaths.writableLocation(QStandardPaths.HomeLocation)
print(repr(default_path))  # 'C:/Users/O P'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()

bundle_path, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(window, "Create New Bundle",
                                             default_path,
                                             "Bundle (*.deb)")
print(repr(bundle_path))
```

The code works as expected when trying to save to a path without space (e.g. 'C:/test.deb') or when executing on macOS.

Comment: If the string is exactly as you wrote above, then it's invalid, since it has unescaped backslashes. Please provide the string value exactly as it is (just replace the name with something else, that's irrelevant, the character syntax is what matters). If you want to use the annoying backslashes for paths, they must be *doubled* in order to be escaped, otherwise just use normal slashes, since they are standard and work fine even on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, @musicamante. I didn't think of that. The string is actually as provided: `C:\Users\O P\Documents` (identifying data removed). The value is set using `settings.setValue("default_path", os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents"))` and the dialog defaults to the correct directory as expected.

Comment: Note that the string above still contains single backslashes. If that's what you get when *printing* it, then it's fine (since printing *does* escaping), but you must be aware of the difference when reporting such aspects: to ensure that you get the actual *unescaped* string printed in output, use `print(repr(someString))`. In any case, it's unclear when you get that error: in your previous comment you say that the dialog opens in the correct directory, and `getSaveFileName()` shouldn't check for existing files (on the opposite, it allows selecting any legal path, even if it doesn't exist).

Comment: Isn't it possible that you're getting the error *after* the dialog is closed? Did you try to use a *hardcoded* file path (remember escaping if you're using backslashes!)? Did you try to convert backslashes to standard ones? `path = somePath.replace('\\', '/')`. Also, please provide a more comprehensive [mre].

Comment: I fixed the path separator issue by swapping `os.path` for `QStandardPath`, and made proper MRE. The issue persists, though, which makes me wonder if the issue could be with the way PySide QFileDialog deals with paths internally.

Comment: QStandardPath doesn't do any magic, it just returns a string for the path with standard slashes, which you can get by doing `replace()` as explained above. Can you explain *in detail* the procedure you follow in order to get that message? Because right now it's not clear if you just type a new file name, a full path or select an existing file from the file list.